# How to write rspec with mocking

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to write an `rspec` test by mocking this method. Should I break this method up, as it doing multiple things?

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'checkerror'
class Operations
    def initialize
        @check
  end
    def result (result_log: File.new('result.txt', 'a+'))
      if @check.errors.empty?
 result_log.write("#{@check.checker.file_path} :: No offensenses detected\n")
#checker is instance of CheckError class
  puts "#{@check.checker.file_path} :: No offensenses detected\n"
      else
        @check.errors.uniq.each do |err|  puts "#{@check.checker.file_path} : #{err}\n"
 result_log.write("#{@check.checker.file_path} : #{err}\n")
 end
end
result_log.close
end
  end
end
```

If @check.errors need to be stuubed with a value and check the execution block.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be awkward mocking the `f` object in your current implementation, due to this line:

```
f = File.new('result.txt', 'a+')
```

You'd need to write something weird in the `rspec` test, like:

```
allow(File).to receive(:new).with('result.txt', 'a+').and_return(mock_file)
```

So instead, I'd recommend using **dependency injection** to pass the file into the method. For example:

```
def check_result(results_log: File.new('result.txt', 'a+'))
  if @errors.empty?
     # ...
end
```

Now, your `rspec` test can look something like this:

```
let(:results_log) { Tempfile.new }
it "prints errors to log file" do
  wharever_this_object_is_called.check_result(result_log: results_log)
  expect(result_log.read).to eq("checker_file_path.txt :: No offences detected\n")
end
```

Comment: As for your question on "Should I break this method up?", that's difficult to say without more context. What is the `check_result` actually supposed to be achieving?? It's a bit weird that it just *logs errors* instead of directly returning a useful result (e.g. `true/false`), and it's weird that you're logging each result twice: Once to a file, and again to STDOUT.

Comment: @NSRaghuwansi Fair enough (although IMO it's a dumb requirement, but whatever). Even so, I'd probably then opt to pass an array of logging outputs - like `check_result(logs: [$stdout, File.new('result.txt', 'a+')])`. But whatever, it's not a very complex method so not a huge issue.

Comment: @NSRaghuwansi *"the condition true or false"* -- I don't understand your question. As for external resources on the topic, there are countless articles, examples and videos about the subject; you're more than capable of looking them up. I don't have a specific one to recommend.

Comment: @NSRaghuwansi It's hard to give concrete advice without a [mcve]; you never showed what `@errors` actually is, or what class this `check_result ` method is defined in. I mean, you *could* mock the value using `instance_variable_set('@errors')`, but there's almost certainly a better way. Like, could you not just run this method in one context that's expected to return errors, and in another context that's not expected to return errors?

Comment: @NSRaghuwansi It's still not really a [mcve], because you haven't shown how the `Operations` class is being *used*. In fact, I don't think that class makes sense at the moment, because you're not initialising it with a `path` and setting the `@path` instance variable to anything.

Comment: But for example, as I keep saying, my advice would be to pass in "real files" instead of trying to mock these internal implementation details. For example: `tmpdir = Dir.mktmpdir('my-temporary-directory'); tempfile = Tempfile.new('test-file.rb', tmpdir)` - then *write something* in the `tmpfile`, and pass the `tmpdir` into your `Operation`'s initializer.

Comment: Or like, what is `@checks_to_run`?? You're not defining it anywhere!!

Comment: can you please checkout the question again. I stucked in this problem and wont able to go ahead

Comment: @check.checker.file_path also need to be mocked